# Array with only one loop must be used

Tags: arrays

I attempted the problem.I have spent much time on this but I am not getting it.

Problem : Given an array of ints, return true if it contains no 1's or it contains no 4's.

```
no14([1, 2, 3]) → true
no14([1, 2, 3, 4]) → false
no14([2, 3, 4]) → true    

  public boolean no14(int[] nums) {

  for(int i=0;i<nums.length;i++)
  {
    if(nums[i]==1 || nums[i]==4)
    return false;

    else 
    return true;
  }

  return false;
}
```

Comment: which programming language? java?  What error do you get? What doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
public boolean no14(int[] nums) {

    boolean containsOne = false;
    boolean containsFour = false;

    for (int i=0; i<nums.length; i++) {
       if(nums[i] == 1) {
           containsOne = true;
       }
       if(nums[i] == 4) {
           containsFour = true;
       }
    }

    if (!containsOne || !containsFour) {
       return true;
    } else {
       return false;
    }

}
```

*(not tested, focus on human readability)*

Hope it will work!

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is, checking if say first number in array is say 2, then you are returning true then and there as your if condition doesnt gets satisfied and you return true form there.

Instead in a loop if you find that current element in an array is either 1 or 4 then only return back false. If you evaluate each entry of array and find that you don't have 1's or 4's in array then return true like:

```
for(int i=0;i<nums.length;i++){
   if(nums[i]==1 || nums[i]==4) {
       return false;
   }
}
return true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `else` in the loop and return `true` after the loop.

```
public boolean no14(int[] nums) {
  for(int i=0;i<nums.length;i++) {
    if(nums[i]==1 || nums[i]==4) return false;
  }

  return true;
}
```